# How to create an array of objects in VC++2010?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I need to build an array to contain objects. However, it does not work and I could not find out the error myself. Please help

```
 # include "CRegistration.h" //My object class
```

SKIP MANY LINES

```
    public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        array<CRegistration^> ^CregArray = gcnew array<CRegistration^>(100);
        record_number = 0;
    }


private: System::Void MyAdd_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         Form2^ myForm2 = gcnew Form2();
         if (myForm2->ShowDialog()==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
            record_number = record_number + 1;
            CRegistration^ Creg = gcnew CRegistration(System::Convert::ToString(record_number),myForm2->TempReg[0],myForm2->TempReg[1],myForm2->TempReg[2],myForm2->TempReg[3]);
            CregArray[record_number-1]  = Creg;



         }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change line

```
array<CRegistration^> ^CregArray = gcnew array<CRegistration^>(100);
```

to

```
CregArray =  gcnew array<CRegistration^>(100);
```

add field declaration:

```
Form1(void) 
{ 
   ..
} 

array<CRegistration^> ^CregArray; 

private: System::Void MyAdd_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { 
    ..
 }
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2065: 'CregArray' : undeclared identifier c:\users\marco\desktop\cs351\hw3\project3\Form1.h 28 1 Project3